# (JAVA) Как в BufferedReader словить слово "налету"?

Tags: java

Есть такая задача: пишем что-то в консоль, как только было введено слово "load" то сразу же, без нажатия клавиши Enter, выводилось сообщение "Hello!". Т.е. оно должно налету поймать данную последовательность символов и сразу запустить какой-то метод.
Написал такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        String str = br.readLine();
        StringTokenizer razbivkaNaSlova = new StringTokenizer(str, " ,.!?(){}\n\t");
        while (razbivkaNaSlova.hasMoreTokens()) {
            words.add(razbivkaNaSlova.nextToken());
        }
        if (words.get(words.size() - 1).equals("load")) {
            System.out.println("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

но метод вызывается только после нажатия на Enter. Как сделать так, чтобы запускалось налету без нажатия Enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) для отдельных символов или InputStream.read(byte[]) для последовательности

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));  
int val;  
while ((val = is.read()) != -1) { 
   if(val == (int)'H'){
     doSomething();
   }
}
```

Comment: попробовал ваш метод (ввожу ту же букву 'H', и по идее должно сразу же запустить, например, System.out.println("Hello")), все равно хочет Enter (с Enter метод срабатывает).

Comment: Это уже настройки терминала, для Windows надо вызвать SetConsoleMode для выставления ENABLE_LINE_INPUT в 0, тогда будет читать посимвольно.

Comment: Этот вопрос под другими названиями уже обсуждался. Пришли к выводу, что без native никак не заставить Java читать без Enter.